# Google geocode. Parsing JSON issue

Tags: php, json, geocode

I want to get a users city, state/province, country from a google geocode of their postal/zip code (canada/usa). I retrieve the data as JSON: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON

The problem is that there is not always the same amount/order of 'address_components'. I was using just like: `$geocodedinfo['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['short_name'];`
But I soon realized that that will not always be province/state because sometimes google will add an extra element under 'address_components'.

Is there a way to parse the results just for the specifics I need (ie: City, State/Province, Country)?

**EDIT** I actually decode the JSON when I get it `json_decode($result, true)`

```
Array
(
[results] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [address_components] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [long_name] => V2X 2P6
                                [short_name] => V2X 2P6
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => postal_code
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [long_name] => Maple Ridge
                                [short_name] => Maple Ridge
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => locality
                                        [1] => political
                                    )

                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [long_name] => Maple Ridge
                                [short_name] => Maple Ridge
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => administrative_area_level_3
                                        [1] => political
                                    )

                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [long_name] => Greater Vancouver Regional District
                                [short_name] => Greater Vancouver Regional District
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => administrative_area_level_2
                                        [1] => political
                                    )

                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [long_name] => British Columbia
                                [short_name] => BC
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => administrative_area_level_1
                                        [1] => political
                                    )

                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [long_name] => Canada
                                [short_name] => CA
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => country
                                        [1] => political
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [formatted_address] => Maple Ridge, BC V2X 2P6, Canada
                [geometry] => Array
                    (
                        [bounds] => Array
                            (
                                [northeast] => Array
                                    (
                                        [lat] => 49.2214351
                                        [lng] => -122.6577849
                                    )

                                [southwest] => Array
                                    (
                                        [lat] => 49.219268
                                        [lng] => -122.663613
                                    )

                            )

                        [location] => Array
                            (
                                [lat] => 49.2202679
                                [lng] => -122.660587
                            )

                        [location_type] => APPROXIMATE
                        [viewport] => Array
                            (
                                [northeast] => Array
                                    (
                                        [lat] => 49.2217005303
                                        [lng] => -122.6577849
                                    )

                                [southwest] => Array
                                    (
                                        [lat] => 49.2190025697
                                        [lng] => -122.663613
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [types] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => postal_code
                    )

            )

    )

[status] => OK
)
```

Comment: I use the XML rather than the JSON, but I have to iterate through until I find the one with the data I need.

Comment: I had the same problem but fir my case I needed most of address_components   So I used a foreach() to get what I want and forget the rest.

Comment: @ayeshk would it be possible to loop over the array and just get the ['long_name'] value WHERE ['types']['0'] == 'country' for isntance? I have never done this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to loop over the results.
Most of the relevant PHP functions don't support multidimensional arrays, and the ones that do will be looping anyway.

You'll probably want something like this:

```
foreach ($geocodedinfo["results"] as $result) {
    foreach ($result["address_components"] as $address) {
        // Repeat the following for each desired type
        if (in_array("country", $address["types"])) {
            $country = $address["long_name"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just what I needed. And now I know about the in_array function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try looking at this, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php it's for looping over arrays, you can do something like,

```
foreach ($result['results'][0]['address_components'] as $key => $val) 
    { 
    if (in_array('country', $result['results'][0]['address_components'][$key]['types'][0])) 
    { 
    echo $result['results'][0]['address_components'][$key]['long_name']; 
    } 
}
```

Something like that should work

Comment: This won't catch results where the values in `types` are in a different order, i.e. `["political", "country"]` - you'll want to use `in_array`.

Comment: Edited my answer to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the results through a `foreach` loop and get the data out you are looking for.

I'm taking a best guess at the meanings of the Google types, I may be off on those.

```
$translate = array(
    'locality' => 'city',
    'administrative_area_level_3' => 'area', // not sure what this one is
    'administrative_area_level_2' => 'county', // regional district ?
    'administrative_area_level_1' => 'state', // province
    'country' => 'country',
    'postal_code' => 'zip', // postal code
);

$address_components = array( );
foreach ($geocodedinfo['results'][0]['address_components'] as $component) {
    $address_components[$translate[$component['type'][0]]] = $component['long_name'];
}

var_dump($address_components);
```

Answer (score -1):

// parse the json response
   `$jsondata = json_decode($data,true);`
   `$results = $jsondata['results'][0];`
   `$addr =$results['formatted_address'];`

This allows you to access the long formatted address

326 London Road, Newbury, Berkshire, West Berkshire RG14 2DA, UK